# Store random numbers in an array without adjacent repeats

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, random

I want to store random numbers in an array without repeats with in the range 0-9. It is fine if they repeat but not if they are right next to each other like: 1577984 is incorrect(because of the double 7s) but 151515 is theoretically okay.

I've been working at this a day or two now and this is my original base code:

```
public static int[] createRandomNumber(int characters){
    int randomNumberArray[] = new int[characters];
    for(int i =0; i<characters; i++){
        randomNumberArray[i] = (int)(Math.random()*9);
    }
    return randomNumberArray;
 }
```

And this is what I have now but it is doing the exact opposite of what I want it's generating all of the same number:

```
public static int[] createRandomNumber(int characters)
{
    int randomNumberArray[] = new int[characters];
    int random = (int)(Math.random()*9);
    for(int i = 0; i <characters ; i++)
    {
        randomNumberArray[i] = random;
        if(randomNumberArray[i] == random)
            randomNumberArray[i] = (int)(Math.random()*9);
        else if(randomNumberArray[i] != random)
            randomNumberArray[i] = random;
    }
    return randomNumberArray;
}
```

Is there a simple solution that I am just not seeing? I've probably rewritten this method 50 times.
Just so you know the parameter code is

```
int characters = in.nextInt();
```

so just the length of their randomly generated password that they want. Also I know that Math.random is pseudo-random but this isn't for real or anything. Plus there's more methods that generate random letters and such as well. (And yes I've done lots of research but no one seems to have my particular problem and believe me asking questions is a last resort for me.)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: That doesn't sound like random numbers to me.

Comment: What do you mean? I didn't want to do the Random r = new Random if thats what you are referring. I also stated above that it IS pseudo-random.

Comment: If you're setting up rules for the randomness, then it isn't really random is it?

Comment: Do you suggest a better way? Any way at all. Secure random maybe?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Randomness can have constraints. Pick up any probability text and look up "[conditional probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability)."

Comment: @pjs sure, but if some numbers are more like to appear than others, then the randomness is limited. That's all. I'm sorry, I wasn't trying to start an argument.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Not an argument, I just want to clarify what seems to be a common misconception on SO. Randomness is a binary classification: a potential outcome either is random or it isn't.  If the outcome can be predicted _with certainty_, it's not random. If there's _any_ uncertainty, it's random. Since OP's array values cannot be predicted with certainty, they are random. If you want to measure the degree of uncertainty, look to entropy. Uniform distributions have maximum entropy. Non-uniform distributions such as normals, binomials, etc., have lower entropy but are still random.

Comment: @pjs - fair enough, I was talking about entropy.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen This is one of those cases where people's intuition about the distribution is wrong. Add a loop to the `main` I wrote below, crank out 10k or 100k lines of output, and load them into your favorite stats package. Build histograms for each column. It turns out that you're equally likely to get any of the values 0-9 in any column! I'm not asking you to take that on my say-so, you can easily confirm it for yourself. Adjacent columns are slightly negatively correlated with each other, but still uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `for` loop, you are assigning `random` to the number array.  But then you are immediately checking if `random` is equal to that spot you just assigned, which is always `true`.  So it picks another random number, which also may or may not be equal to the previous digit.

I've rewritten the `for` loop to have a `while` loop in its body, to keep checking versus the *previous* digit to see if there is a repeated digit.

```
for(int i = 0; i <characters ; i++)
{
    randomNumberArray[i] = random;
    // If not first, check if it matches the previous digit
    while(i >= 1 && randomNumberArray[i - 1] == random)
    {
        random = (int)(Math.random()*9);
        randomNumberArray[i] = random;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it is working now! And of course now that i'm looking at it, it makes perfect sense, duh! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible solution based on a do-while:

```
class TestArrayGen {
   public static int[] createRandomNumber(int characters) {
      int randomNumberArray[] = new int[characters];
      randomNumberArray[0] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
      for(int i = 1; i < characters; i++) {
         do {
            randomNumberArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
         } while(randomNumberArray[i] == randomNumberArray[i-1]);
      }
      return randomNumberArray;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for(int number : createRandomNumber(20)) {
         System.out.print(number + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Note that I've also boosted the multiplier to 10, you'll never get a 9 otherwise.

Comment: Good catch on the multiplier!